# Advice is not executing for custom annotation used at method level and it seems problem with poincut , any suggestions?

Tags: java, spring, spring-aop

My advice in the following aspect is not getting executed:

```java
package com.xxxx.logging.core.config;

import org.aspectj.lang.JoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.ProceedingJoinPoint;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.AfterThrowing;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Around;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Pointcut;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Aspect
@Component
public class LogingAspectHandler {

    @Autowired
    CustomAppender lCustomAppender;

    //@Pointcut("execution(@com.xxxx.logging.core.config.CustomLogged * *(..))")
    @Pointcut("@annotation(com.xxxx.logging.core.config.CustomLogged)")
    public void customAnnotated() {}

    @Around("customAnnotated()")
    public void customLogger(ProceedingJoinPoint lProceedingJointPoint) {
        System.out.println("Get it "+lProceedingJointPoint.getSignature().getName());
        lCustomAppender.logEntryLevelInfo(lProceedingJointPoint);
          
    }
}
```

I have created a custom annotation named `CustomLogged` with `Target(ElementType.METHOD)` and using it at method level in a class within package `com.xxxx.logging.core.config`. Now I want a pointcut for all those methods which are annotated with `@CustomLogged`.

Please find the source code link  
https://github.com/ssnarvariya/July_Projects.git

Comment: Welcome to SO. Your question does not constitute an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), which is the preferred way to ask questions here and dramatically improves your chances to receive helpful answers. Nobody can compile an incoherent set of code snippets, therefore nobody can reproduce your problem. Probably, the problem is in the portion of the code/configuration you are hiding from us. so please edit the question, then leave a comment here. The pointcut looks OK to me. Does the aspect kick in if you change it to `execution(* com.xxx.mypackage..*(..))`?

Comment: @kriegaex thanks for letting me know the problem with my post , I have edit the question and also gave a try to change the pointcut expression you mentioned but still it is not executing.

Comment: What was unclear about the term [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @kriegaex I again re edited the question and I hope this will suffice to understand the problem, any more info required pls let me know , will update here. With regarding MCVE , being a newbie slowly will learn the process.

Comment: Besides, I reformatted your question before, now again you are using weird quotations for your own text. I am going to fix that again, it looks weird. I do not mean to be unfriendly, really. But please do listen to my advice. I am sure if I had the MCVe, I could solve your problem in 2 minutes. Writing this here takes much longer. It is a waste of time for both of us, and my time is limited. You are also suffering, waiting for your solution longer than necessary.

Comment: I have gone through that article, earlier my whole idea was to explain the problem without proper MCVe. I cannot post entire or minimal project on GitHub due to organisation restricted policies. Thanks for your time and valuable suggestions. Let's close it here , I would like to put my time to fix the problem rather than commenting here because now it really looks weird. Niehter you are going to understand the problem without proper MCVe nor I am going post the same thing here again and again.

Comment: You still do not seem to understand what MCVE means. I do not need a copy of your full project with confidential code. An MCVE is a minimal, abstracted version of it, just enough to reproduce the problem. You can rename all packages and classes, strip them down to do nothing else than is necessary to reproduce the problem. If you call yourself a developer, you should be able to do it. You don't need to add anything, only remove as much as possible. It does not get much easier than that, every developer can do that. Don't use company policies as an excuse, they don't apply to an MCVE.

Comment: Did that only while posting the code on SO. I replaced packages name with xxxx etc and also it's not excuse (git link doesn't open - restricted access). I can only post required classes with minimal and required code to reproduce the problem on SO and I already did that. The last thing I can do is to create a replica project of same on my personal machine and reproduce the problem. Then I will upload the same on git and will share a link to you. FYI I am not saying company policies apply to MCVe and also I am not making any excuse

Comment: No, for the 3rd time: You did **not** post an MCVe here, only an aspect. You really need to pay a bit more respect to the people trying to help you by thoroughly reading their messages. Quoting myself: _"No, it does not suffice, because in order to understand why an aspect might not be working as expected, I need **full aspects** incl. imports and package names, **full application classes** and **full configuration**. All three could be wrong or contain information necessary to debug."_ So where are your application code and configuration, please?

Comment: @kriegaex Please find the updated post with project source code link

Comment: I really apologize for being a disrespectful and appreciate your patience. I never meant to be in that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for the MCVE on GitHub. There are so many problems in your application, without the full project I would never have been able to find out what is wrong with it. Among other things, you have these problems:

- Your aspect has not one, but two `@Around` advices. None of them proceeds to the original method. This has the effect that only the first advice gets triggered (whichever Spring AOP finds first), but never the second one. And also, your original method is never called. Therefore, both advices need to call `lJoinPoint.proceed()`. In `@Before` or `@After` advices, this is not necessary, but in `@Around` it is, hence the parameter type `ProceedingJoinPoint` (not a simple `JoinPoint` like in the other advice types).
- Spring AOP only works on Spring-managed components or beans, but you instantiate your `EVMLogger` instance by simply calling a static factory method outside the control of Spring. Therefore, Spring AOP can never create an AOP proxy for this class and never intercept any method calls on it. The `@CustomLogged` annotation on method `public void debug(Object lMsg)` has no effect.
- Also in `EVMLogger`, you save a `Logger` instance in a static variable, but actually if you want a different `Logger` for each class using `EVMLogger`, you cannot overwrite this static field. You have to make it an instance field and set it whenever you create a `EVMLogger` instance.
- That you need multiple `EVMLogger` instances, also means that you cannot use a singleton bean but should use a prototype bean. There are several ways to [instantiate a parametrised prototype bean](https://medium.com/davebarda/creating-a-dynamically-initialized-bean-in-spring-18d6d41d24df) dynamically. I am showing you how to auto-wire the application context into target class constructors needing the `EVMLogger` and there to get a bean instance from the context. This applies to two different classes in your example.

One more thing that looks weird to me, is that your aspect logs what `EVMLogger` does, i.e. a logger loggging infos about another logger. But maybe your aspect does something else in reality and logging was just for the sake of the MCVE. I am assuming it is so.

I created a [pull request](https://github.com/ssnarvariya/July_Projects/pull/1) for your convenience. The key commits are:

- https://github.com/ssnarvariya/July_Projects/pull/1/commits/c8ed9aab
- https://github.com/ssnarvariya/July_Projects/pull/1/commits/597d8ccd

The console log when calling `curl http://127.0.0.1:8080/getreq` looks like this:

```
Inside logEntryLevelInfo for method ::showSampleData
Inside logEntryLevelInfo for method ::tryService
{"@timestamp":"2021-07-02T19:49:54.879+07:00","@version":"1","message":"Debug Msg...","logger_name":"org.ssn.app.config.CustomLogService","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"app_msg":{"mthd_name":"tryService","mtd_args":["Message1"]}}
Inside logCustomAnnotatedInfo for annotated method ::debug
{"@timestamp":"2021-07-02T19:49:54.879+07:00","@version":"1","message":"Custom Debug Msg...","logger_name":"org.ssn.app.controller.TestController1","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"app_msg":From Controller---}
{"@timestamp":"2021-07-02T19:49:54.879+07:00","@version":"1","message":"Debug Msg...","logger_name":"org.ssn.app.config.CustomLogService","thread_name":"http-nio-8080-exec-1","level":"DEBUG","level_value":10000,"app_msg":{"mthd_name":"showSampleData","mtd_args":[]}}
```

You see that

- there are two distinct logger names `CustomLogService` and `TestController1` and
- both aspect advices fire now.

Comment: Thanks it not only solve my problem, it also highlighted my mistakes and helped me to learn. Once again thanks for code review along with helpful review comments.